# Action in a REST API

Tags: rest, api, http, restful-architecture

The web service for my app is an Express server that I'm trying to keep as RESTful as possible.

I have a `/timesheets` route. Here a `GET` request obviously fetches a list of timesheets. Also, `POST` naturally creates a timesheet.

I need to, however, send an *instruction* to my web service to **"sign off"** on a set of timesheets for a certain `paycycle` (again another resource).

Providing sign-off for a set of timesheets in a paycycle isn't a resource, but an action, in my opinion. What would be the suggested best practice way for me to structure my web service?

Comment: The most commonly accepted practice is to use POST for operations that don't fit the usual RESTful style. I would just POST to /signoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking about 'signing off' as an action, you can rephrase this by thinking of 'being signed off' as a state. REST deals with transferring state, so this suddenly becomes easier.

So if some resource looks like this (using JSON because it's what everyone does):

```
{
  "signedOff" : false
}
```

Then the implication is that you can send a `PUT` request that sets this to:

```
{
  "signedOff" : true
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution! It might be especially handy if a time sheet and a pay cycle actually the same entity internally.

Comment: Yea! Almost everything can be rephrased this way. Not everything that feels like an action is a good fit for REST, but this certainly is.

Answer (score -1):

The possible solution would be to send a `POST` request to:

```
/paycycle/{paycycleId}/sign-off/
```

with the body:

```
{
  "time_sheet_id": {timesheetId}
}
```

, where `{timesheetId}` is ID of a time sheet, and `{paycycleId}` is ID of the pay cycle you want to sign off from.